# Flutter images loading issue after reload display but not first time

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

Trying to display cover image based on bookList which is RxList from getX but after hot reload it displays that particular book only. Need to load it instantly as soon as the page load.

Tried setstate too but UI is not updating the first time. Please help. Thank you.

Below is the screenshot images not getting displayed first time but after hot restart.

Here images problem:

[image]

HorizontalGrid Widget which based on horizontalGridTitle open the specific book

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:matab/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:matab/controllers/cart_book_controller.dart';
import 'package:matab/models/book.dart';

import 'package:matab/ui/pages/styles.dart';

import '../../../controllers/book_controller.dart';

import '../../general_widgets/book_magazine_tapbar.dart';
import '../../general_widgets/my_network_image.dart';
import '../item_details/book_details_page.dart';

class HorizontalGrid extends StatefulWidget {
  final String horizontalGridTitle;

  const HorizontalGrid({Key? key, required this.horizontalGridTitle})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HorizontalGrid> createState() => _HorizontalGridState();
}

class _HorizontalGridState extends State<HorizontalGrid> {
  late RxList<dynamic> bookList;
  final BookController bookController = Get.find(tag: 'bookController');

  final CartBookController cartBookController =
      Get.find(tag: 'cartBookController');
  @override
  void initState() {
    bookList = bookController.getSpecifiedBooks(widget.horizontalGridTitle);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 20, 20, 20),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                widget.horizontalGridTitle.tr,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: secondaryColor,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Get.to(() => BookMagazineTapbar(
                        titleText: widget.horizontalGridTitle,
                      ));
                },
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "seeAll".tr,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: mainColor,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, color: mainColor)
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 20, 10),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 140,
                    child: GridView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      gridDelegate:
                          const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 1,
                      ),
                      itemCount: bookList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return SizedBox(
                            child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  bookList[index].coverImage;
                                  Get.to(BookDetailsPage(
                                    type: Constants.bookConst,
                                    index: index,
                                    cartButtonText: 'addToCart'.tr,
                                  ));
                                },
                                child: Obx(
                                  () => CachedNetworkImage(
                                    key: widget.key,
                                    imageUrl: bookList[index].coverImage,
                                  ),
                                )));
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is called based on

```
  getSpecifiedBooks(String title) {
        // debugPrint("requested book is $title");
        if (title == Constants.recommendedConst) {
          debugPrint("recommended requested");
          return recommendedBooksList;
        } else if (title == Constants.latestByMatabConst) {
          return latestBooksList;
        } else if (title == Constants.onSaleConst) {
          return onSaleList;
        } else if (title == Constants.favoritesConst) {
          return favoriteBookList;
        } else if (title == Constants.allItemsConst) {
          return bookList;
        } else if (title == Constants.searchConst) {
          return bookList;
        } else {
          return [];
        }
      }
```

Afterwards data coming from firebase perfectly in latestBooks:

```
RxList<dynamic> latestBooks = await databaseService.getLatestBooks();








    Future<RxList> getLatestBooks() async {
        RxList books = [].obs;
        RxInt itemCount = 1.obs;
    
        Query<Map<String, dynamic>> booksQuery = firestoreInstance
            .collection('books')
            .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
            .limit(10);
    
        await booksQuery.get().then(
          (value) {
            for (var doc in value.docs) {
              Book bookItem = Book(
                author: doc['author'],
                title: doc['title'],
                price: doc['price'].toDouble(),
                coverImage: doc['coverImage'],
                bookID: doc.id,
                ratings: doc['ratings'].toDouble(),
                description: doc['description'],
                discountPercentage: doc['discountPercentage'],
                isLiked: false,
                itemCount: itemCount,
              );
              books.add(bookItem);
            }
          },
        );
    
        return books;
      }




Finally latestBooks is assigned to latestBooksList:

  final latestBooksList = [].obs;

latestBooksList.assignAll(latestBooks);
```

Comment: Can you try to use `Obx(() => )` next to your gridView Builder and not inside it? because every time the list changes you should update also the `bookList.length`.

Also, in the CachedNetworkImage try to use `progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, downloadProgress) => CircularProgressIndicator(value: downloadProgress.progress)` property aswell

Comment: tried Obx there too still not getting updated.

Comment: Did you try also in Debugging mode to check if `bookList[index].coverImage` is not null in the beginning